# Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type void* to NSString*__strong* is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I got the above error when migrate to ARC.  Here is the code:

```
static NSString *cashBalanceKeyPath = @"test";

...

[xxx forKeyPath:cashBalanceKeyPath options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:&cashBalanceKeyPath];

...

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {

    if (&cashBalanceKeyPath == context)   < error here
    {
      ...
    }
```

When I used bridge:

```
if (&cashBalanceKeyPath == (__bridge NSString *)context)
```

I got the error: `Comparison of distinct pointer types (NSString *__strong* and NSString *)`

How can I make the conversion?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did the comparison even work with MRC?

Comment: Yes.  The comparison works fine with MRC (without ARC).  It can implicit conversion.

Comment: The original comparision `&cashBalanceKeyPath == context` looks OK even under ARC. You are not comparing any objects, not even casting objects to plain pointers. What is the original compile error?

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you exactly why, but you don't get a warning or error if you swap the order of the comparison:

```
if (context == &cashBalanceKeyPath) {
    // ...      
}
```

Comment: Ick! You are right, and I don't know offhand why either - bug or C conversion rules (in any other language one wouldn't think of that as an option, but in the C family...). I wouldn't advise relying on this.

Comment: This is what I *assume/guess*: The right-hand-side of `==` is cast to the type of the left-hand-side. Casting `NSString **` to `void *` is allowed with ARC, but the opposite direction is forbidden.

Comment: This is interesting, because the original comparision looked right and shoudln't emmit errors. Swapping operands did the trick of silencing the error.

Comment: I believe that the order matter.  (context == &cashBalanceKeyPath) is c pointer comparison.  (&cashBalanceKeyPath == context) is NSSting pointer comparison.  In first case you don't need conversion, but in later case you do need conversion.

Comment: @user2543991: `if (&cashBalanceKeyPath == (NSString * __strong *)context)` does also work.

Comment: Checked the Standard. The order of the operands should *not* matter, any pointer to an "object" (that is in the C sense not Obj-C sense) can be compared to a `void *`. I'd say this is the ARC logic getting in a twist. You'll see from my answer that adding an explicit `void *` cast works - you shouldn't need a bridge here. We appear to have the compiler treating a symmetric operation asymmetrically. @MartinR, maybe a bug report?

Comment: @CRD: I agree that `==` should behave symmetrically and that this looks like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using the *address* of a variable as a unique tag, so there are no memory management/ownership issues here. To do the address comparison cast the address of the variable to void:

```
if ((void *)&cashBalanceKeyPath == context)
```

That seems to give the compiler all it needs without any bridge cast.

Comment: Right. In fact, question author didn't share the original error/warning message that leaded to doing bridge. Maybe it was just incompatible pointers?

Comment: @iMartin: I think the original error message is in the question title.

Answer (score 1):

If you strip out the `__strong` in the error message, it's clearer what's going on:

```
Comparison of distinct pointer types (NSString ** and NSString *)
```

`&cashBalanceKeyPath` is a pointer to an NSString object, or a `NSString**`, while context is being cast to an `NSString*`, or a plain NSString object (which it isn't).

So to fix the problem, change the cast to be `(NSString * const *)`, the const is apparently required to appease ARC.

Comment: if (&cashBalanceKeyPath == (__bridge NSString **)context) I got the error: pointer to non-const type NSString * with no explicit ownership

Comment: This gives "error: pointer to non-const type 'NSString *' with no explicit ownership"

Comment: @user2543991 Yeah, made a mistake there. Updated to use the proper cast now

Comment: `const` is the wrong pointer ownership attribute.  ARC is expecting `__autoreleasing`,

Answer (score 0):

as `cashBalanceKeyPath` is a pointer and `context` is a pointer the correct way to compare this two is:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == (__bridge void *)(cashBalanceKeyPath)) {

    }
}
```

and the call should be:

```
[xxx addObserver:self forKeyPath:cashBalanceKeyPath options:0 context:(__bridge void *)(cashBalanceKeyPath)];
```

I wonder how your code could work with MRC.

Comment: `context` is expecting to contain **address of the object, not the object itself**. Your comparision will never pass.

Comment: After your edit: Yes, if he would use the object itself as `context` your solution would be right. But, he is using address of the object (pointer to object).

Comment: you are right, but i think its just ridiculous to use a pointer this way.

Comment: Why? He avoided bridging. The string is static so no lifetime management, anyway.

Comment: yes, but whats the content of `&cashBalanceKeyPath`? Its completly random. `cashBalanceKeyPath` IS the pointer. `&cashBalanceKeyPath` is just some address you dont know anything about. This could be anything.

Comment: @JonathanCichon: The address of a static variable is constant throughout the lifetime of a program and a common method (as I think) to get a unique context pointer.

Comment: if it would be an integer or so i would agree to use `&` but not with a static `NSString`. And it looks like ARC thinks so too. Maybe i just cant see the advantage of using the indirect way over just comparing the pointer values.

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem can probably be avoided by writing

```
static int cashBalanceKeyPathContext = 0;
```

and using &cashBalanceKeyPathContext as the context.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're getting the error is because you're comparing a string and a pointer to a string, when you really just want to compare two strings. When you're comparing two strings, you should use `isEqualToString`. So your code might look like this:

```
NSString *contextString = (__bridge NSString *)context;
if ([contextString isEqualToString:cashBalanceKeyPath])
{
    //Do something
}
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, he does not want to compare strings. `context` is the address of the `cashBalanceKeyPath` variable and just used as a unique pointer.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood this particular question. I've had this issue before and solved it with this, but my situation was different as you pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to compare strings you should be using the method isEqualToString:

Comment: The down vote because he isn't interested in string equality. In observeValueForKeyPath a context is passed in that needs to be identified. The context can be _anything_. For simplicity, he chose to pass the address of a static variable as the context, and is trying to check whether the context matches the address of the static variable.

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

ARC generally doesn't like __strong when it comes to string and Apple recommend that you use copy.

Comment: "copy" can be used for a NSString *property*, but that is a completely unrelated topic. I don't see any property declaration in the question.